# How to override any HttpHeader in response of WebClient?

Tags: java, spring, webclient, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

```
WebClient.builder().baseUrl("/").filter(contentTypeInterceptor()).build();
```

How can I modify the `Content-Type` of the received response (because I'm receiving a response from a webserver that emits the wrong content type. As I'm not in control of the external server, I'd like to correct the content type for further correct processing (eg with jackson library etc).

```
private ExchangeFilterFunction contentTypeInterceptor() {
    return ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor(clientResponse -> {
        org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ClientResponse.Headers headers = clientResponse.headers();
        //TODO how to headers.setContentType("myval) or headers.set("Content-Type", "myval");   
        //headers.asHttpHeaders(); cannot be used as it is readonly
    });
}
```

The question could be answered in general how to override any http header.

The root cause in my case is that I receive `text/html`, but the response body is actually a `application/xml`. And `jackson` rejects parsing that response due to:

`org.springframework.web.reactive.function.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: Content type 'text/html' not supported for bodyType=MyResponse`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ahmed's response is technically correct. However, I believe that at the time of my posting this, that `ClientResponse.from()` is deprecated, and you should use the `.mutate()` method to create a new Builder.

```
private ExchangeFilterFunction contentTypeInterceptor() {
    return ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor(clientResponse -> 
        Mono.just(clientResponse.mutate()
            .headers(headers -> headers.remove(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE))
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
            .build()));
}
```

Comment: Indeed the `.mutate()` was introduced due to an issue of mine regarding my question: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/24126 , so this is the correct answer nowadays.

Answer (score 4):

I had similar issue and the accepted answer didn't work with me.
I done this instead, in order to override an invalid content-type that i was receiving.

```
/**
     * webclient interceptor that overrides the response headers ...
     * */
    private ExchangeFilterFunction contentTypeInterceptor() {
        return ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor(clientResponse -> 
            Mono.just(
                    ClientResponse
                        .from(clientResponse) //clientResponse  is immutable, so,we create a clone. but from() only clones headers and status code
                        .headers(headers -> headers.remove(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE)) //override the content type
                        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE) 
                        .body(clientResponse.body(BodyExtractors.toDataBuffers()) ) // copy the body as bytes with no processing
                        .build()));
    }
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because it changes the *response*, not the request.

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like this?

```
private ExchangeFilterFunction contentTypeInterceptor() {
    return ExchangeFilterFunction.ofRequestProcessor(clientRequest -> 
        Mono.just(ClientRequest.from(clientRequest)
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
            .build()));
}
```

Comment: Great, that works. Though I'd be interested in performance drawbacks for creating a new `ClientRequest` object here?

Comment: well you have no other options since `ClientRequest.class` is an immutable interface https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/ClientRequest.html api docs: `public interface ClientRequest Represents a typed, immutable, client-side HTTP request`.

Comment: If that's the only way, I wonder why it has been designed that way... Thank you so far for providing a working solution!

Comment: because immutability helps with thread safety. Many threads might touch that object and if you can mutate it it can lead to a lot of problems. My personal opinion is that mutability is bad, really bad because it can lead to very complicated bugs.

Comment: As of spring 5.1.9 it will be possible to set different `MimeType` in the `Jaxb2XmlDecoder`: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/23278